# nodesize parameter ignored in randomForest package

Tags: r, random-forest

Does the `randomForest` package ignore the `nodesize` parameter? When I predict the terminal nodes for a dataset and check the counts, I see values that are less than the `nodesize`. I would submit a fix for this myself but the underlying code was written in Fortran. If someone can confirm this behavior I will reach out to the package maintainer and hopefully start a fix.

```
> library(randomForest)
> set.seed(1)
> rf <- randomForest(mtcars[,-1], mtcars[,1], nodesize = 5)
> nodes <- attr(predict(rf, mtcars[,-1], nodes = TRUE), 'nodes')

# node counts of first tree
> table(nodes[,1])

# first row is the terminal node ID#, second row is the count
 2  6  9 10 11 14 15 16 18 19 
 5  3  3  6  4  2  3  1  3  2
```

**Adding system info:**

```
Session info----------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.98.1049)         
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Chicago             

Packages--------------------------------------------------------------------
 package      * version date       source        
 randomForest * 4.6.10  2014-07-17 CRAN (R 3.1.1)
```

Comment: Did you hear anything from the package maintainer? I have the same issue...

Comment: He told me that it's coded to the original specification by Breiman and Cutler and that he will only be changing the documentation. To address this, I have been post-processing the RF by predicting and dropping the nodes that fall below my nodesize comfort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from package maintainer:

> That parameter behaves as the way that Leo Breiman intended.  The bug
>   is in how the parameter was described.  It’s the same as `minsplit` in
>   the `rpart:::rpart.control()` function:
>
> > the minimum number of observations that must exist in a node in order
> >     for a split to be attempted.
>
> I will change the description in the help file in the next version to
>   resolve this confusion.
>
> Best, Andy